# WCF Web Service Client throwing 404 EndPointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, binding

I have a solution that includes a WCF web service project and a WPF client project, which work fine locally. I have a dedicated IIS web server onto which I have deployed the WCF web service project. The IIS site is configured with an SSL cert and is set to require SSL. The site has an HTTPS binding, bound to a specific DNS host name and all IP addresses (there is only one), on the default port.

I can access the endpoint address and WSDL in a browser on the server or the client without issue. The organisation uses a proxy server but I don't think that's getting in the way and there is no firewall between the client and the server.

Here is my web.config on the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="DefaultBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None">
                            <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
                        </transport>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="Hca.Ims.Wcf.ImsService">
                <endpoint 
                 name="Hca.Ims.Wcf.ImsService"
                 address="/ImsService.svc"
                 binding="wsHttpBinding"
                 bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding"
                 contract="Hca.Ims.DataAccess.DataContracts.IImsDataContract" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And here is my client app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    [...]
    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="false" />
    </system.net>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="DefaultBinding" receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:30:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" >
                            <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
                        </transport >
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://mydnsname/ImsService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
             bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding" contract="ImsService.IImsDataContract"
             name="Hca.Ims.Wcf.ImsService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And here is some calling code:

```
var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
//Works
var webResult = webClient.DownloadString("https://mydnsname/ImsService.svc");

var wcfClient = new ImsDataContractClient("Hca.Ims.Wcf.ImsService");
//Crashes
var wcfResult = wcfClient.GetUserInfo("SomeUserId");
```

Result:

EndPointNotFoundException:
There was no endpoint listening at https://mydnsname/ImsService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Inner Exception:
"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Can anyone see what I've done wrong? Incidentally, I started out with a basicHttpsBinding which had the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I had tried to use relative paths in the endpoint addresses. They don't work. Once I put the full URLs in the web.config endpoint addresses, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have a contract mismatch.

Your server is setup for this contract;

```
contract="Hca.Ims.DataAccess.DataContracts.IImsDataContract"
```

Your client endpoint is setup for another contract

```
contract="ImsService.IImsDataContract"
```

These need to match.

Comment: ImsService.IImsDataContract is the copy of the contract created in auto-generated code when I add a service reference. That does seem to work when I run it. Almost as soon as I posted the question I found the solution which I've just posted. Thanks anyway.